# Bash - String replacement with special characters

Tags: replace, awk, sed

#### First question:

How may I replace a string with special characters like sha512 encrypted string to another string with special characters using sed or awk or any other way?

#### Example

```
$6$random_salt$gGxk7E7kZE/bpfLsQ8mUt/BuL.VQ5SAbk.FaTQXV/seUjkIoLwnOfZXch/5CPEG5SYeHtWmykBQ898OkA6HMX1
```

to let's say:

```
$6$other_salt$dfkjdHsj1ghkJHJHwsjx11njJHd/.1djBkdfSAbk.FaTQX..!skjd.5CPEG5SYedsfsdmddslkHtWmykBQ8df98
```

in a line in a file containing keyword 'crypt'

#### Second:

How I may replace double quotation with signle quotation on such lines. I have a script replacing passwords variables in puppet manifests. The issue is that puppet by default uses double quotation to define password fields. I wish to include sha512 crypted password by using single quotations

#### Example

from

```
class user {
    password => "$6$other_salt$dfkjdHsj1ghkJHJHwX..!skjslkHtWmykBQ8df98"
}
```

to

```
class user {
    password => '$6$other_salt$dfkjdHsj1ghkJHJHwX..!skjslkHtWmykBQ8df98'
}
```

Comment: It's better to ask two questions separately. Also, how do you want to get from `gGxk7E7...` to `dfkjdHsj...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

I used `|` as seperator.

```
sed -e 's|$6$random_salt$gGxk7E7kZE/bpfLsQ8mUt/BuL.VQ5SAbk.FaTQXV/seUjkIoLwnOfZXch/5CPEG5SYeHtWmykBQ898OkA6HMX1|$6$other_salt$dfkjdHsj1ghkJHJHwsjx11njJHd/.1djBkdfSAbk.FaTQX..!skjd.5CPEG5SYedsfsdmddslkHtWmykBQ8df98|' file
```

Second:

`\x27` (hex) represents `'`

```
sed -e '/password/{s/"/\x27/g}' file
```